# Horizontal touch scrolling on IE10

Tags: touch, internet-explorer-10, horizontal-scrolling

I have turned off horizontal scrolling by using the `-ms-touch-action: pan-y;` style. However I now have a child div that I need horizontal scrolling on. I have added the style:

```
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;
```

This works fine, however it still allows the default behaviors of IE10 to take over, swipe back to previous page etc. Is there a way to get horizontal scrolling whilst preventing the browser actions, or do I need to write a custom scrolling script using the `MSPointer` events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
-ms-scroll-chaining: none;
```

to the element that has

```
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466007.aspx